# Order List C# by custom function with optimal performance

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have a function

```
public float GetOBJECTActivity(OBJECT ob){

   // returns some float
}
```

and inside another function, I get a list of OBJECT (`List<OBJECT>`)
that I want to sort according to the `GetOBJECTActivity` function result (descending ot ascending).

How can I do that in optimal performance in C#? I will doing similar operations a lot in my project and I want to make sure I use the fastest way and most elegant.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What is the context of this?  Is this rocket science or just a pet project? It's always better to provide as much context as possible so we can help you.  "How can I do that optimally" can be quite subjective.

Comment: Well I do not want to make a comparer class for each comparison I want to do.

Comment: Just make 1 comparer class, and use it for all the comparisons

Comment: no I will have different compare functions similar to `GetOBJECTActivity`, say `GetOBJECTLikes` and that will make two comparer classes right?

Answer (score 0):

Make a [Comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx), and then use that comparer with [List.Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx)

By far the fastest and most elegant way to get your list sorted, is to let the built in functions do it.

A lot of types(floats, strings, ints) have built in comparers, so if you know that those are the only types you are going to use, than you can just call `List.Sort()`

Comment: I do not want to make comparer classes for each comparison I want to perform.

Comment: if you think I do not understand your answer, elaborate more

Comment: @Saher I gave you 2 links in my answer.  You should click them

Answer (score 0):

```
static int MyActivityComparison(OBJECT a, OBJECT b)
{
    float x = GetOBJECTActivity(a);
    float y = GetOBJECTActivity(b);

    // ascending
    return x.CompareTo(y);

    // descending
    // return y.CompareTo(x);
}

list.Sort(MyActivityComparison);
```

Or with a lambda expression, if you don't want to define a standalone function:

```
list.Sort((a, b) =>
    {
        float x = GetOBJECTActivity(a);
        float y = GetOBJECTActivity(b);
        return x.CompareTo(y);     // ascending
        // return y.CompareTo(x);  // descending
    });
```

Comment: if you could just `return x.CompareTo(y)` then you wouldn't even need a comparer in the first place.

Comment: @SamIam Note that x and y are of type `float`, not `OBJECT`.  Therefore `CompareTo` exists.

Comment: I think the lambda expression is what I need. Thanks I will try that